# How to make custom plugin run on demand?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm trying to make a plugin which would run either by itself at a specific time or when it is triggered manually(that is, a particular function of the plugin is triggered). I'm not understanding how to implement that though and googling around hasn't been fruitful.

If that may help, this is **briefly** how the function looks like.

```
function rrikesh_insert_post()
{
  $post = array([variables populated from external file]);
  wp_insert_post($post, true);
}
```

Anyone can suggest a way?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run scheduled events using [wp_cron](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron).

To trigger it manually you'll need to create an admin screen and create a button that triggers the function. To do that read up on [Creating a Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and [Adding Admin Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus).